# Finding the method in ASP.NET back-end

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, refactoring

I'm refactoring some piece of... code, part of huge, complex .Net project. There is a piece of code like

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" CommandName="Update" ... />
```

Notice the command name, *genius*, who wrote the code called it simply **Update**. As the project is huge, you can imagine how many "Update" methods are there. I need to find that method very badly, is there any way I can get a call stack or something?

Comment: Does the tag have an OnCommand attribute assigned, either declaritively or programatically in the code behind files. Do a search for all references to "btnSave" in the designer.cs file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might not be used anywhere, especially if there are no other buttons with other `CommandName`s in this context.

You will find it (if it exists) in the button click event handler, where the value would be compared against the string "Update".

Assuming C#, it would be something like:

```
public void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button b = sender as Button;

    if(b != null)
    {
        if(b.CommandName == "Update")
        {
           // handler the update command
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Strange, I searched through solution, not a single comparison of "CommandName" to "Update"

Comment: @Nordvind - Exactly the point of the first paragraph of my answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks =) Problem is, there are some buttons with that property, and I see no other ways for those buttons to interact with back-end, rather than using that "CommnadName".

Comment: @Nordvind - The click event of the button would be hooked up. The command name is just an identifying string for buttons that are within a templated control to differentiate them.

Answer (score 3):

The `CommandName` parameter is commonly used when putting buttons inside a `DataGrid`, `GridView` or some similar control. These clicks are handled in the [ItemCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.itemcommand.aspx) event handler of the DataGrid (or in the [RowCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx) event of the GridView), where `e.CommandName` is checked to find out *which* button has been clicked.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting, I'll look for it!

Answer (score 1):

The code-behind of that page has a Click handler for that button. The "Update" is read in that method, not executed.